# Java Object Class

Tags: java, class, object

consider the statement :

Every class has a super class [ True/ False ]

I feel it should be false as Object is the base for all which do not have super class.

What should be the proper reply.

Answer (score 7):

Your answer is correct asb. Just to slightly fix the terminology,

- `Object` is a superclass of all other classes
- `Object` doesn't have a superclass

Answer (score 2):

False. There's always someone at the "top of the food chain"

Comment: Or in this case, a class at the top of the parent chain

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking of Java?

If that is the case, the proper reply is false.

Your reasoning is correct: Object is the base class for all classes so all classes except Object have a super class.

The important part of this question is to remember that even if a class doesn't extend another class, it is still implicitly extending Object.